# Are there evidences in Vedas or real proofs that prove that gotra is NOT a Biological concept in Brahmins?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, gotra

Generally gotra is passed on to biological son. But is it possible that there are people (Brahmins) who are of same gotra but don't share a common ancestor?